# Virtual serial port

Tags: windows, serial-port

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Faking an RS232 Serial Port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605721/faking-an-rs232-serial-port)

I'm developing an app that uses a COM serial port. In order to test logic of my applicantion, I think one solution is using a Virtual COM port instead a pipe, for example.

Do you know any software for this purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found another alternative that is open source: http://sourceforge.net/projects/com0com/

This works really well, but needs a little bit more config.

**EDIT:** [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COM_port_redirector#Open_source_solutions) you can find lot of them, open source and freeware.

Comment: but how create something like com0com?

Answer (score 4):

Eterlogic.com has Virtual Serial Ports Emulator.  Free on win32, works great for me.

Comment: I was using this one, but I'm using 64 bits windows. Any other alternative?