# How can you access a serial port from two different processes (Python)

Tags: python, serial-port, multiprocessing

I would like to use multiprocessing (to avoid GIL issues on multi core machines) and have a read process and a write process using the same serial port.  Is that possible?  If so, how do I get the port acquired and then how do I get the child processes file objects that they can use?

Edit -- This needs to work on Windows, but Mac and Linux would also be nice.

Comment: Of course you can, at least on Unix platforms, but you'll have to use some kind of synchronization mechanism between the processes.

Comment: Why would I need synchronization mechanisms?  The serial port is full duplex, right?

Comment: Ah, you mean one process reads and one writes? That shouldn't be a problem, I guess. (Not a serial comms expert, though.)

Comment: Full duplex mean input/output communication can be done together. That's doesn't mean multiple process can use it at the same time. A serial port can be attached only one, only one client can take the port and talk at time.

Comment: Yep.  I want one process to write, and another process to read.  I will use a queueing mechanism to interact with another process that is actually making sure that the synchronization of the actual protocol is correct.

Comment: @tito, are you saying there's no way to somehow "dup" the serial port handle and use it in a child process (or child processes)?  I thought a child process inherits all of the file handles of its parent?

Comment: In case of fork, i think the fd will be available for both process (totally not sure about the split here). But then, you'll still have to have a lock/sync mechanism to do write at the same time, or read at the same time. That's look silly. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605721/faking-an-rs232-serial-port

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in the comments, only one process can acquire the serial port at a time - therefore the way to go is to create yet another process, possibly using Python xmlrpc, or jsonrpc, that will do the actual hardware I/O, and modify your current read and write scripts to call remote functions on that other process.

The example in the library documentation should be enough for implementing such "I/O server process" with xmlrpc:
http://docs.python.org/library/simplexmlrpcserver.html