# Creating virtual serial port with C#

Tags: c#, virtual-serial-port

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Faking an RS232 Serial Port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605721/faking-an-rs232-serial-port)

I have an application that reads data from serial port. To test the application i would like to create a virtual serial port that generates data and puts the the port at the same PC, so that the other app can access that data.

Any idea how?

Thanks

Comment: http://com0com.sourceforge.net/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605721/faking-an-rs232-serial-port

Comment: I used com0com. Works great for me.

Comment: ohw ok.. so there is no way that you can create a fake com port in c#?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have used **[com0com](http://sourceforge.net/projects/com0com/)** tool for this. It has no direct API, but you can write an application (or a method) which starts a new com0com process to set up / modify your virtual ports "on the fly" with commandline parameters.