# Adding a virtual null-modem port to a USB-RS232 adaptor

Tags: serial-port, usb, virtual-serial-port

I have a USB-RS232C adaptor. Plugging it into my computer nicely provides a COMx port.

The device I want to connect to specifies that `SD` and `RD` should be switched. My assumption is that this refers to the channels more commonly specified as `RxD` and `TxD`. The tool used to do this (in the absence of rewiring) is a 'null-modem' adaptor.

Is it possible to emulate the presence of a null-modem adaptor on the computer, to save

- buying a physical adaptor
- rewiring the existing cable
- writing some obscenely convoluted driver?

This question ([Faking an RS232 Serial Port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605721/faking-an-rs232-serial-port)) has some answers that look plausible, but they seem to refer to emulating the entire setup - I already have a COM port and just want to switch a pair of signals.

Comment: No, there is no way to emulate what you need.  No, a driver cannot substitute for a null-modem adapter.  You have to perform the swap somewhere in hardware so that the input is connected to an output (rather than input to input and output to output).

Comment: Try to search for Virtual Null Modem. On Windows I have used this application in the past.